# How can I insert the i value into the variable?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have 5 `textFields` and they are in sequence `book1TextField, book2TextField.book3.,book4.,book5`. I want variable `i` to be inserted in these `textFields` so it will be like `book(i)TextField.getText()` so that I don't have to do this one by one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    bookQuantities[i] = Integer.parseInt(book1TextField.getText());
    System.out.println(bookQuantities[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When those `TextField`s are created you should store them in an `ArrayList<TextField>` to be accessed at a later time. Then you can easily write something like:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < bookTextFields.size(); i++) {
    bookQuantities[i] = Integer.parseInt(bookTextFields.get(i).getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instanceof like this:

```
int comp = panel.getComponentCount();
int[] bookQuantities = new int [comp];
for (int i = 0; i < comp; i++) {
    if (panel.getComponent(i) instanceof JTextField) {
        JTextField txt = (JTextField) panel.getComponent(i);
        bookQuantities[i] = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
        System.out.println(bookQuantities[i]);
    }
}
```